Applying itplr-kosit/validator for XRechnung
I am trying to use the validator on https://github.com/itplr-kosit to validate an UBL-invoice conform to XRechnung.
In the documentation, under
https://github.com/itplr-kosit/validator?tab=readme-ov-file#standalone-command-line-interface
there are some examples like
java -jar  validationtool-<version>-standalone.jar --help.
So I would expect to find something fitting the pattern validationtool-<version>-standalone.jar in the repository; but I cannot find such a file.
How did I search?

git clone https://github.com/itplr-kosit/validator
cd validator
find . -iname *.jar

The only found *jar file was ./libs/de/kosit/validationtool/packaged-test-scenarios/1.0.2/packaged-test-scenarios-1.0.2.jar
What am I missing?
ThankU

https://github.com/itplr-kosit/validator/releases

you will find the jars  if you extract the release
https://github.com/itplr-kosit/validator/releases/tag/v1.5.0
To validate XRechnung you will additionally have to extract the validator-config release from https://github.com/itplr-kosit/validator-configuration-xrechnung in the same directory.
The -r parameter seems to accept absolute paths only, so in windows I usually run
java -jar validationtool-1.5.0-java8-standalone.jar -r %cd% -s scenarios.xml  -h testfiles\my.xml

in cmd or
java -jar validationtool-1.5.0-java8-standalone.jar -r $PWD -s scenarios.xml  -h testfiles\my.xml

in powershell respectively to use the current path as basis.
kind regards
Jochen
